# SPARQL queries to extract the necessary data from the triple store

Tags: sparql

I am learning linking data using nodejs on a project. I am linking open Linked data for top50 spotify songs in nodeJS, the data is linked successfully as it brings all the fields. But when i run it with Where clause in GraphDB query editor to show the specified results, the query does not return any results.

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX mo: <http://purl.org/ontology/mo/%22>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT ?artist ?name 
    WHERE {

        ?x rdf:type mo:MusicArtist ;
        foaf:name ?n ;
        rdfs:label ?artist.
filter( regex(?n, "Ed Sheeran" ))
       }
    LIMIT 20

Whereas the following query runs successfully.
SELECT  ?name ?genre ?artist
        WHERE { 
            ?x rdf:type rdfs:Class ;
           mo:ArtistName ?artist ;
           foaf:name ?name ;
           dbo:genre ?genre .
}

What possibly am i doing wrong in WHERE clause.
```

Comment: without knowing what data you loaded impossible to answer ... long story short, the first query then doesn't match any data. try to debug your query, i.e. use only a subset of the triple patterns. Also you should check if the entity with a `foaf:name` "Ed Sheeran" is in your dataset.

Comment: you should also always use `regex(str(?n), "Ed Sheeran" )` and keep in mind that `regex` will be slow. if you don't need it, use some other way to match names or use a fulltext index if the triple store does support (which GraphDB does) - but indeed, the `regex` has to work if the data matches

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have used FILTER without using REGEX.
 FILTER(?name="Ed Sheeran") And this worked for me.

Comment: now you're mising up both queries. it should be `FILTER(?n="Ed Sheeran")` or not as the variable in the first query is `?n`. Also, please try again with `str` function: `regex(str(?n), "Ed Sheeran" )`

Comment: fix the "PREFIX mo: xxxx". remove the %22 at the end and try again.